# Eliminate Ref# Reference Does Not Exist Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, referenceerror

In the `UpdateDemogInfoDA` script, I allow the user to enter new information, capture that in another worksheet (JBD) and then overwrite the old info with the new info in the Sample Data tab.

Then when new look up button is pushed, the formulas to look up based on the `CustID` populate. For some reason, and only for certain cells like Directions and Keycode, the data is getting converted to:

> REF#! Reference Does Not Exist error.

I cannot figure out why. I am including the code for both the `NameSearchDA` and the `UpdateDemogInfoDA` in hopes that I am missing something that is obvious to you. I'm open to any suggestions on cleaning it up as well so it runs faster.

I have ensured that all cells in the Sample Data are not merged by running `.breakapart()`. I have ensured that the JBD cell reference is pulling the data for the right cell from the Customer Center.

My spreadsheet is <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1noCiboVB5_yTq9H0W_-q9goqc4E9Gq0DhcNMuXj9Kz4/edit#gid=622975187>

The 3 tabs are DA Customer Center, JBD (temp holding place for data to copy) and Sample Data (the main database).

I usually use Jay R Levesque as my sample customer. If you hit the search by name button, you can select the user and then select the address from the drop down. This populates that CUST ID and then all the formulas drive from that unique ID.

```
    function UpdateDemogInfoDA() {
    
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sample Data');
    var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg1.getValues();
    var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('JBD');
    var id=sh2.getRange('DU2').getValue();
    var JBDdata=sh2.getRange(2,2,1,137);
      
       
      
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][0]==id) {
    JBDdata.copyTo(sh1.getRange(i+1,2,1,137),{contentsOnly:true});
    ss.toast("Match found. Demographics Updated");
    
        break;
         }
     }
```

Code for SearchByName

```
function NameSearchDA(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DA Customer Center");
var filters = ss.getSheetByName("Filters");

var name = sheet.getRange("C9");
var allnames = filters.getRange("A2");
var address=sheet.getRange("C11");
var name2address=filters.getRange("E2");
var valname = allnames.getDataValidation();
var valaddress=name2address.getDataValidation();

var custid=sheet.getRange("H7");
var contractrenewal=sheet.getRange("H8");
var name = sheet.getRange("C9");
var alladdress = filters.getRange("A12");
var prevcust=sheet.getRange("C10");
var address=sheet.getRange("C11");
var zip=sheet.getRange("C12");
var phone = sheet.getRange("C13");
var email = sheet.getRange("C14");
var city=sheet.getRange("E12");
var source=sheet.getRange("H12");
var altphone=sheet.getRange("G13");
var altemail=sheet.getRange("G14");
var altcontact=sheet.getRange("C15");
var type=sheet.getRange("G15");
var contactphone1=sheet.getRange("C16");
var contactphone2=sheet.getRange("G16");
var contactemail=sheet.getRange("C17");
var mailbox=sheet.getRange("C19");
var ccbox=sheet.getRange("E19");
var emailbillbox=sheet.getRange("G19");
var mailingaddress=sheet.getRange("C20");
var startdate=sheet.getRange("H20");
var wintermailaddress=sheet.getRange("C21");
var enddate=sheet.getRange("H21");
var keycode=sheet.getRange("G22");
var directions=sheet.getRange("C23");

var custidmatch = "=iferror(index('Sample Data'!$A:$Q,Match($C$9&$C$11,'Sample Data'!$D:$D&'Sample Data'!$F:$F,0),1))";
var contractrenewdatematch = "=if(H7>0,filter('Sample Data'!$B:$B,'Sample Data'!$A:$A=$H$7),\"\")";
var prevcustmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$C:$C,'Sample Data'!$A:$A=$H$7),\"\")";
var zipmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$G:$G,'Sample Data'!$A:$A=$H$7),\"\")";
var citymatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DX2:$DX8499,'Sample Data'!$A2:$A8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var sourcematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$AI2:$AI8499,'Sample Data'!$A2:$A8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var phonematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$E$2:$E$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var altphonematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DD$2:$DD$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var emailmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$K$2:$K$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var altemailmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DE$2:$DE$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var altcontactmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DF$2:$DF$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var typematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DG$2:$DG$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var contactphone1match = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DH$2:$DH$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var contactphone2match = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DI$2:$DI$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var contactemailmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DJ$2:$DJ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mailboxmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EF$2:$EF$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ccboxmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EG$2:$EG$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var emailbillsboxmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DP$2:$DP$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mailaddressmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$J$2:$J$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var wintermailaddressmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DS$2:$DS$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var startdatematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DQ$2:$DQ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var enddatematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DR$2:$DR$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var keycodematch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DO$2:$DO$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var directionsmatch = "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$O$2:$O$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";

custid.setFormula(custidmatch);
contractrenewal.setFormula(contractrenewdatematch);
prevcust.setFormula(prevcustmatch);
zip.setFormula(zipmatch);
city.setFormula(citymatch);
source.setFormula(sourcematch);
phone.setFormula(phonematch);
altphone.setFormula(altphonematch);  
email.setFormula(emailmatch);
altemail.setFormula(altemailmatch);
altcontact.setFormula(altcontactmatch);
type.setFormula(typematch);
contactphone1.setFormula(contactphone1match);
contactphone2.setFormula(contactphone2match);
contactemail.setFormula(contactemailmatch);
mailbox.setFormula(mailboxmatch);
ccbox.setFormula(ccboxmatch);
emailbillbox.setFormula(emailbillsboxmatch);
mailingaddress.setFormula(mailaddressmatch);
wintermailaddress.setFormula(wintermailaddressmatch);
keycode.setFormula(keycodematch);
startdate.setFormula(startdatematch);
enddate.setFormula(enddatematch);
directions.setFormula(directionsmatch);

name.setDataValidation(valname);
address.setDataValidation(valaddress);

var size1= sheet.getRange("K9");
var size2= sheet.getRange("K10");
var size3= sheet.getRange("K11");
var size4= sheet.getRange("K12");
var st1=sheet.getRange("L9");
var st2=sheet.getRange("L10");
var st3=sheet.getRange("L11");
var st4=sheet.getRange("L12");
var uvbulb=sheet.getRange("L13");
var ht1=sheet.getRange("N9");
var ht2=sheet.getRange("N10");
var ht3=sheet.getRange("N11");
var ht4=sheet.getRange("N12");
var mod1=sheet.getRange("P9");
var mod2=sheet.getRange("P10");
var mod3=sheet.getRange("P11");
var mod4=sheet.getRange("P12");
var uvmod=sheet.getRange("P13");
var ser1=sheet.getRange("Q9");
var ser2=sheet.getRange("Q10");
var ser3=sheet.getRange("Q11");
var ser4=sheet.getRange("Q12");
var uvser=sheet.getRange("Q13");
var lcd1=sheet.getRange("R9");
var lcd2=sheet.getRange("R10");
var lcd3=sheet.getRange("R11");
var lcd4=sheet.getRange("R12");
var uvlcdr=sheet.getRange("R13");
var wellloc=sheet.getRange("K14");
var wellyear=sheet.getRange("K15");
var welldepth =sheet.getRange("M15");
var wellGPM =sheet.getRange("O15");
var wellcasing =sheet.getRange("Q15");
var pumpdate=sheet.getRange("K16");
var pumpsize =sheet.getRange("M16");
var presstankdate =sheet.getRange("O16");
var presstanksize =sheet.getRange("Q16");
var systemnotes=sheet.getRange("K17");
var iron=sheet.getRange("J19");
var manganese=sheet.getRange("J20");
var pH=sheet.getRange("J21");
var hardness=sheet.getRange("J22");
var arsenic=sheet.getRange("L19");
var radon=sheet.getRange("L20");
var uranium=sheet.getRange("L21");
var lead=sheet.getRange("L22");
var chloride=sheet.getRange("N19");
var nitrate=sheet.getRange("N20");
var fluoride=sheet.getRange("N21");
var bacteria=sheet.getRange("N22");
var tannins=sheet.getRange("P19");
var other=sheet.getRange("P20");
var smell=sheet.getRange("P21");
var citywater=sheet.getRange("P22");
var labtestfreq=sheet.getRange("K23");
var lastlabdate=sheet.getRange("O23");
var nextlabdate=sheet.getRange("Q23");
var saltdelfreq=sheet.getRange("K24");
var saltqty=sheet.getRange("M24");
var lastsaltdate=sheet.getRange("O24");
var nextsaltdate=sheet.getRange("Q21");
var callaheadbox=sheet.getRange("S24");

var size1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$AZ$2:$AZ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var size2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BE$2:$BE$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var size3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BJ$2:$BJ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var size4match= "=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BO$2:$BO$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var st1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BA$2:$BA$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var st2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BF$2:$BF$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var st3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BK$2:$BK$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var st4match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BP$2:$BP$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var uvbulbmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BU$2:$BU$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ht1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BB$2:$BB$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ht2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BG$2:$BG$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ht3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BL$2:$BL$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ht4match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BQ$2:$BQ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mod1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BC$2:$BC$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mod2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BH$2:$BH$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mod3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BM$2:$BM$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var mod4match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BR$2:$BR$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var uvmodmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BW$2:$BW$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ser1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BD$2:$BD$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ser2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BI$2:$BI$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ser3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BN$2:$BN$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ser4match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BS$2:$BS$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var uvsermatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BX$2:$BX$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lcd1match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EA$2:$EA$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lcd2match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EB$2:$EB$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lcd3match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EC$2:$EC$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lcd4match="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$ED$2:$ED$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var uvlcdrmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EE$2:$EE$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var welllocmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BY$2:$BY$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var wellyearmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$BZ$2:$BZ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var welldepthmatch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CA$2:$CA$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var wellGPMmatch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CB$2:$CB$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var wellcasingmatch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CC$2:$CC$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var pumpdatematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CD$2:$CD$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var pumpsizematch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CE$2:$CE$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var presstankdatematch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CF$2:$CF$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var presstanksizematch ="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CG$2:$CG$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var systemnotesmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CH$2:$CH$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var ironmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CP$2:$CP$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var manganesematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CQ$2:$CQ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var pHmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CR$2:$CR$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var  hardnessmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CS$2:$CS$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var arsenicmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CJ$2:$CJ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var radonmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CI$2:$CI$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var uraniummatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CK$2:$CK$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var leadmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CN$2:$CN$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var chloridematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CT$2:$CT$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var nitratematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CM$2:$CM$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var fluoridematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CW$2:$CW$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var bacteriamatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CL$2:$CL$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var tanninsmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$EH$2:$EH$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var othermatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CO$2:$CO$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var smellmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CU$2:$CU$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var citywatermatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$CV$2:$CV$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var labtestfreqmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DV$2:$DV$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lastlabdatematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DW$2:$DW$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var saltdelfreqmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$AL$2:$AL$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var saltqtymatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$AM$2:$AM$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var lastsaltdatematch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$AJ$2:$AJ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";
var callaheadboxmatch="=if(H7>0, filter('Sample Data'!$DZ$2:$DZ$8499,'Sample Data'!$A$2:$A$8499=$H$7),\"\")";

custid.clearContent();
contractrenewal.clearContent();
name.clearContent();
prevcust.clearContent();
address.clearContent();
zip.clearContent();
city.clearContent();
source.clearContent();
phone.clearContent();
altphone.clearContent();
email.clearContent();
altemail.clearContent();
altcontact.clearContent();
type.clearContent();
contactphone1.clearContent();
contactphone2.clearContent();
contactemail.clearContent();
mailbox.clearContent();
ccbox.clearContent();
emailbillbox.clearContent();
mailingaddress.clearContent();
startdate.clearContent();
wintermailaddress.clearContent();
enddate.clearContent();
keycode.clearContent();
directions.clearContent();

address.setDataValidation(valaddress);
name.setDataValidation(valname);

custid.setFormula(custidmatch);
contractrenewal.setFormula(contractrenewdatematch);
prevcust.setFormula(prevcustmatch);
zip.setFormula(zipmatch);
city.setFormula(citymatch);
source.setFormula(sourcematch);
phone.setFormula(phonematch);
altphone.setFormula(altphonematch);  
email.setFormula(emailmatch);
altemail.setFormula(altemailmatch);
altcontact.setFormula(altcontactmatch);
type.setFormula(typematch);
contactphone1.setFormula(contactphone1match);
contactphone2.setFormula(contactphone2match);
contactemail.setFormula(contactemailmatch);
mailbox.setFormula(mailboxmatch);
ccbox.setFormula(ccboxmatch);
emailbillbox.setFormula(emailbillsboxmatch);
mailingaddress.setFormula(mailaddressmatch);
wintermailaddress.setFormula(wintermailaddressmatch);
keycode.setFormula(keycodematch);
startdate.setFormula(startdatematch);
enddate.setFormula(enddatematch);
directions.setFormula(directionsmatch);
size1.setFormula(size1match);
size2.setFormula(size2match);
size3.setFormula(size3match);
size4.setFormula(size4match);
st1.setFormula(st1match);
st2.setFormula(st2match);
st3.setFormula(st3match);
st4.setFormula(st4match);
uvbulb.setFormula(uvbulbmatch);
ht1.setFormula(ht1match);
ht2.setFormula(ht2match);
ht3.setFormula(ht3match);
ht4.setFormula(ht4match);
mod1.setFormula(mod1match);
mod2.setFormula(mod2match);
mod3.setFormula(mod3match);
mod4.setFormula(mod4match);
uvmod.setFormula(uvmodmatch);
ser1.setFormula(ser1match);
ser2.setFormula(ser2match);
ser3.setFormula(ser3match);
ser4.setFormula(ser4match);
uvser.setFormula(uvsermatch);
lcd1.setFormula(lcd1match);
lcd2.setFormula(lcd2match);
lcd3.setFormula(lcd3match);
lcd4.setFormula(lcd4match);
uvlcdr.setFormula(uvlcdrmatch);
wellloc.setFormula(welllocmatch);
wellyear.setFormula(wellyearmatch);
welldepth.setFormula(welldepthmatch);
wellGPM.setFormula(wellGPMmatch);
wellcasing.setFormula(wellcasingmatch);
pumpdate.setFormula(pumpdatematch);
pumpsize.setFormula(pumpsizematch);
presstankdate.setFormula(presstankdatematch);
presstanksize.setFormula(presstanksizematch);
systemnotes.setFormula(systemnotesmatch);
iron.setFormula(ironmatch);
manganese.setFormula(manganesematch);
pH.setFormula(pHmatch);
hardness.setFormula(hardnessmatch);
arsenic.setFormula(arsenicmatch);
radon.setFormula(radonmatch);
uranium.setFormula(uraniummatch);
lead.setFormula(leadmatch);
chloride.setFormula(chloridematch);
nitrate.setFormula(nitratematch);
fluoride.setFormula(fluoridematch);
bacteria.setFormula(bacteriamatch);
tannins.setFormula(tanninsmatch);
other.setFormula(othermatch);
smell.setFormula(smellmatch);
citywater.setFormula(citywatermatch);
labtestfreq.setFormula(labtestfreqmatch);
saltdelfreq.setFormula(saltdelfreqmatch);
saltqty.setFormula(saltqtymatch);
lastlabdate.setFormula(lastlabdatematch);
lastsaltdate.setFormula(lastsaltdatematch);
callaheadbox.setFormula(callaheadboxmatch);
```

}

Comment: Wow.  That's a big project.  Personally, I would have used either dialogs or a webapp to perform all data entry and with that amount of data I probably would consider using a database.  I doubt that you'll get much help on this question as it's way to broad.

Comment: My very specific question is "why is the REF#! Reference Not Found error coming up in the directions box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've played with many formatting issues and believe that the Reference Not Found was related to how the data was formatted when being copied.  I applied the same formatting to all cells in the sheet and it appears to have resolved the issue.  Thanks to Cooper for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to make sure that you understand that these lines do not return a value.  They return a range.

```
var name = sheet.getRange("C9");
var allnames = filters.getRange("A2");
var address=sheet.getRange("C11");
```

If you want them to return a value then write them like this:

```
var name = sheet.getRange("C9").getValue();
var allnames = filters.getRange("A2").getValue();
var address=sheet.getRange("C11").getValue();
```

Checkout these references:

1. [GetValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
2. [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Get Values is a preferable method for cell ranges that are contiguous because they return a two dimensional array that can be access very quickly. And often offers a 10X performance improvement in looping scripts.

Comment: I'm kind of new to coding.  But the thought is that I set the range so that, later in the script, I could set or reset the formula for the variable on the next search.